# Split value in a variable using another string and store in array (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a variable *diagnosisCodes* having value as shown below :

```
echo $diagnosisCodes
{"code":"some code1","codeSet":"some set1","description":"some description1"} {"code":"some code2","codeSet":"some set2","description":"some description2"} {"code":"some code3","codeSet":"some set3","description":"some description3"}
```

I want to split these using delimiter `"} {"`, so that I get 3 different values and then store them in an array (in bash).

I found the solution using the below command (suggested by Incrivel Monstro Verde in the comments):

```
IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< $(echo $string | sed 's/{"code/|"code/g;s/\"}/"/g')
```

But this solution would fail if my string has "codeSet" attribute which comes before the "code" attribute.

Comment: What are 3 different values to you? It is not quite clear. What entry do you want to store in the array

Comment: Since there are 3 objects in my string and they are separated by "} {", I was hoping to get each object in different elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use read:

```
#!/bin/bash

string='{"code":"some code1","codeSet":"some set1","description":"some description1"} {"code":"some code2","codeSet":"some set2","description":"some description2"} {"code":"some code3","codeSet":"some set3","description":"some descripti

IFS='{' read -r -a array <<< $(echo $string | sed 's/}//g')

echo "${array[1]}"
echo "${array[2]}"
echo "${array[3]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But if I get either of the curly braces in the data itself like - 
{"code":"some code1","codeSet":"some set1","description":"some {description1}"}
Then this would give different element.

Comment: It's true, in this case. I used your example

Comment: This new case, you can use: IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< $(echo $string | sed 's/{"code/|"code/g;s/\"}/"/g')

Comment: Great, this works fine. But can you think of some other solution because this one would fail if one of the objects doesn't start with "code" attribute like : 
{"codeSet":"some set1","code":"some code1","description":"some description1"}

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
#!/bin/bash

string='{"code":"some code1","codeSet":"some set1","description":"some description1"} {"code":"some code2","codeSet":"some set2","description":"some description2"} {"code":"some code3","codeSet":"some set3","description":"some description3"}'
var="${string//\} {/$'|'}" #replace '} {' with '|' , works for one space only between '} {'
IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< $(echo $var | sed 's/{//g;s/}//g')
for i in "${array[@]}"
  do
    echo $i
  done
```